# how to put CSS styles For 1 specific element

Tags: html, css

For my site, I'm using these 2 effects-[Show footer on scroll down](http://codepen.io/gstricklind/pen/yvtjh) and [show header on scroll up](http://codepen.io/kaemak/pen/mHyKa). But the `.nav-down` and `nav.up` elements interfere with each other, which makes both effects bug. Is there a way to put a style for a specific element?
[Here's my code](http://codepen.io/CookieMonsta/pen/rjZLgb). You see how only the header works, but not the footer?

Comment: To set a style to specific element it could has an id. `#id{styles...}`

Comment: To extend upon the above comment, it's **easiest** if it has an ID. You could also target it with CSS pseudo-selectors such as `:first-of-type`.

Comment: How do I use id's in my case? Cause the javascript says this `$('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');` so the `nav-down` and `nav-up` interfere.

Comment: Setting id is not related to this js code.

Comment: But the point is that the javascript calls 2 elements. However one of those elements is for somethign else. How do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by using the following changes to make oppostive effects to header and footer :

**JQuery**

```
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');

             // I added this 
            $('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() <= $(document).height()){
              $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');

              // I added this 
              $('footer').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
            }
```

**CSS**

```
/* Change the height of footer to become 100px */



 footer {
    height: 100px; /*instead of 50px*/
    }
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do I have to change the  height of footer?

Comment: Because in the codepen you provided, you won't see the footer easily unless you make the footer taller. It will lie behind their tools. Anyway, if it will look OK in your website, leave it as 50px.

Answer (score 0):

I this code:

```
$('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
```

**nav-up and nav-down** are only two class names that one add to header and onother removes.

There is not two elements, only two class name that changes for header element. It means that this code only affects one element **header**. If you have an unwanted effection on your footer, I'm sure that is not related to the code above. You need to search for some thing like this:

```
$('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
```

Comment: when this code gets executed, it call the class `nav-up` and `nav-down`, but the `nav-down` class is for the footer, which causes a problem. How di I fix that?

Comment: Maybe the footer has this classes so, It is a normal thing class names share between elements. But this code has **never never never** any relation to the footer element.

Comment: You must find the real code that changes you footer. So we can help you.

Comment: The footer has this code `$('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');`, same code as the header. I think it's calling the same classes